# What is the name for a film overlay where there is an array of crosses?

Tags: camera, post-processing, space

I've seen this in a lot of animations of spaceships, as well as the intro sequence to The Expanse which I've attached a screenshot of. https://vimeo.com/734114243 is also an example.

[image]

The above screenshot again, but with the contrast boosted:
[image]

While in both cases this overlay has been added in post, what kind of camera setup are they trying to emulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s called a [Résau plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9seau_plate):

> …a transparent sheet of glass or plastic engraved with a grid of crosshatches called [fiducial markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker). It was commonly used in film cameras (before the advent of digital cameras) for scientific and technical photography.

These were [used on several of the cameras on the Apollo missions](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11-hass.html), which is probably where this pattern entered public awareness. From the NASA article linked above:

> The crosses are recorded on every exposed frame and provided a means of determining angular distances between objects in the field-of-view.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!